# Checkbox near multifield value

Tags: 7, entities

I want to make a new content type called **Event**, I have other fields in Event, but the field I am having trouble is *Keynote Speakers*.

**Speakers** are different content types and have their own fields like Name, Address.

In **Event content type** I have a *field entity reference* for this *speakers content type*, where Multiple Speakers could be added. I want to have a **Checkbox** near every speaker which would say Key Speaker as Title and could be checked to make the speakers as Key Speaker.

I tried this with *Field Collection Module*, where I made a collection type of Speakers and inserted the Entity Reference for Speaker as a field value. I created a new *Boolean* field with *checkbox*, but that went on to be

[image: List of speakers]

My quest is to make that **Keynote Speaker** as a separate title and have a checkboxes near every Speaker, if checked they'll be added as Keynote Speaker. Like:
[image: Speakers as how I want in my application]

How do I achieve this ?

Comment: do you want a check box before the name as well as after the name? as shown in the image? or just below Keynote Speaker?

Comment: The speakers are values coming from `Speakers content type`. So, in this content type, I want to add those speakers, as well as if they are Keynote Speakers. So, the second checkbox is not after the name, it is for the Keynote Speaker. If the second checkbox is checked then The user will be added as Keynote Speaker not Normal Speaker.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using two entity reference fields rather than one. One for storing the speakers and another one for storing the keynote speaker.

The you could place these two fields side by side and then hide the label of the keynote speaker through css.

You could also achieve this in a module using the form alter function to alter the style of the form.

Comment: that's one way of doing it... I was hoping some Drupal way of solutions.